# Python BeautifulSoupe4: How to get link from anchor tag without duplicate

Tags: python, css, html, beautifulsoup

```
<a href=”link” class=”link_to_img”>
<img src=”dosen’t matter”></img>
</a>
<span>
<a href=”link” class=”link_to_img”>Title Of Image</a>
</span>
```

As you can see there are two `<a href=”link” class=”link_to_img”></a>` when I try to get the link Example: `href.findAll('a', 'class': 'link_to_img')` it gets the link but it duplicates it and I just need it one time. Is there a way I can target the `<a></a>` inside the `<span></span>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select your link with a `span > a` [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) which would match an `a` tag directly inside a `span` tag:

```
soup.select("span > a")
```

You can additionally check the class:

```
soup.select("span > a.link_to_img")
```

If you are using the latest `beautifulsoup4` package, you can use `select_one()` to have it return a single `Tag` instance instead of a list:

```
soup.select_one("span > a.link_to_img")
```

Comment: Awesome I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [limit argument](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-limit-argument) in findAll().

```
find_all("a", limit=1)
```

Comment: Thank You. Do I need to import anything to use limit ?

Comment: There is also one problem There are more a tags with different links that I don't need I didn't add them for simplicity reasons. I was hopping to get a response that shows how to target a specific a tag do to it's parent tag

Comment: limit is a native filter for the findAll() function so you don't need to import anything. I'm not sure what you're after with your second question but if you need to filter on class as well you can use the class_="link_to_img" filter as well (assuming Beautiful Soup 4.1.2 or higher)

Comment: Why don't use `find("a")` as opposed to `find_all()` with a `limit`?